# How do you simulate memory shortage with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, load-testing

I want to know how my system behaves under a high load. To do so I would like to artificially reduce the amount of memory available to MySQL. How should I do this?

Comment: Install Firefox and open some tabs. :-)

Comment: Although this way of simulating a 'high load' might actually be close to a real situation, you have to watch out what you are testing here and how much it resembles a real load. (Watch out for optimizing based on incorrect assumptions)

Comment: @ceejayoz: your comments is wrong(flame) in so many ways but I had to laugh about it :-)

Comment: a light-weight solution is e.g. `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=2900M`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution would be to run the app and MySQL in a virtualized environment. You can generally control the RAM and number of CPUs to see how it would perform.

Check out http://www.virtualbox.org , it's the best one I've used and it's free.

Comment: It doesn't even matter if your virtualization environment supports that, since Linux does: see the mem= and maxcpus= boot arguments.

Comment: @Ken - Good point. I don't run in Linux most of the time, so I forget these things :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you're on a linux system, you can take advantage of [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html).  Given that a shell uses very little memory, you could open a shell and run:

```
ulimit -m <memory size>
```

to limit the memory for that shell, and then start your MySQL server there.

Comment: I am going to test this with a program(c) I wrote. I want to test if program will exit gracefully when out of memory.